# Device support warning : Google play 2019

Tags: android, performance, google-play

Today I submitted the update to my app and got below [image: severe]

**severe** **warning** but when I compare both apks and everything looks same. Can anyone explain what is warning really mean, I am scared if it excludes some devices or what ? Also both apps support same no. of devices as well i.e ***8133***

new apk :

[image: new apk]

older apk :

[image]

Comment: This looks like a bug in the Google Play Console. I would contact Google Play support via the help menu (? question mark icon) and report it.

Comment: Thanks, I will report it too. This thing make me so scared :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I can see the difference in the screenshots. Look in the "Differentiating ABI details". Your old app seems to support "armeabi". Your new app seems to have mips64, but not armeabi. There aren't many android devices which are armeabi but not arm64 or arm7 so this is probably ok, but that is the difference. It is a change in your native code.

Comment: I didn't used any NDK code, probably updating 3rd party library like realm or exoplayer caused that issue