# unity export 64bit for android

Tags: unity-game-engine, 64-bit

How can i export for android 64bit apk in unity.

there is a solution at this link.
[Unity Export Android 64-bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55974331/unity-export-android-64-bit)

But I use unity 5.5.4p4 personal. There is no ARM64 checkbox.

Comment: update toi latest unity version then

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unity Export Android 64-bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55974331/unity-export-android-64-bit)

Comment: [Android : Ensure that your app supports 64-bit devices](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit#unity_developers) - Unity <=5.6 ► Upgrade to version that supports 64-bit.