# Unity3D - problem with Google Play 64-bit requirement

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, google-play-console

I cannot deploy the .abb nor .apk as I keep getting the 64-bit requirement error in the Google Play Console.

I have tried everything from this answer: [Unity Export Android 64-bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55974331/unity-export-android-64-bit)
 but still the same problem.

- Unity3D version: 2017.4.30f1
- NDK: r13b (Unity is not supporting newer versions but this should not be a problem)
- SDK API Level: 28
- JDK: 1.8.0_221

Player Settings:

[image]

When the Unity builds the package I can see it is building for 64-bit devices so I don't get what is the issue.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build your app without x86.

[x86 usage is very low and it even got deprecated in 2019.2](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2019/03/05/android-support-update-64-bit-and-app-bundles-backported-to-2017-4-lts/), so you wont miss anything by removing it.