# Play Store 64bit apk with 32bit dll

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, arm64

I have Unity project with DLL prepared for architectures: x86, x86_64, armeabi-v7a.
I haven no possibility to convert DLL to architecture arm64-v8a.
However if I build apk for armeabi-v7a only, it works on 64bit device.
But for Google Store I need to build it with arm64-v8a compatibility - this version of application doesn't work because there is error that 64 bit DLL not found.

Is there any possibility to solve this problem?
Maybe there is some possibility to modify apk file after build?

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: You may have the same problem as I had, please check my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57709345/unity3d-problem-with-google-play-64-bit-requirement/57711673#57711673)

Comment: Thanks, however it is different - I need my application to work in arm64 bit build, but using DLL 32 bit (armv7).