# Why does scripting backend slow down android app?

Tags: c#, android, performance, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make an Android app in Unity that uses some heavy computation, when I tried to publish it to the google developer console I got an error "This release is not compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement"

After some digging around I found that I need to change the Scripting Backend to IL2CPP Instead of Mono and un-select x86

Now Google lets me publish the app, but when I build and run it on my phone it is significantly slower, should I be worried about this? If so is there any way to fix this? (when I change Scripting Backend back to Mono and build and run the app doesn't lag any more when it's running, perhaps there are some different settings that I need to use?)

What I read so far was that the Scripting Backend IL2CPP is supposed to be faster as far as when the app is run, but at least on my phone this doesn't seem to be the case

The phone I'm using to test this is a ZTE Blade, Model number Z965 (I think it's called ZTE Blade X but I'm not sure)in case that's useful[image]

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55974331/unity-export-android-64-bit

Comment: Yeah that  post is pretty useful, I used it to make the app comply with Google's new requirements, but complying with Google's requirements makes the app slower which I don't get

Comment: yeah, I put that there for context for answerers. :)

Answer (score 0):

I (might have) found the reason for the lag from this post:

https://forum.unity.com/threads/huge-fps-drops-from-60fps-armv7-to-25-30-fps-arm64-unity-2017-4-20.682018/

It seems that any logging operations take a long time using the ARM64 architecture(I ran the app using the ARMv7 and ARM64 architecture and the ARMv7 didn't lag that much) now that I changed every logging setting to "none" the app seems to run more smoothly(anyway at least I hope that was the only problem)

[image]