# Unity3D - Cannot build 64 bit Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play, 64-bit

I have a problem similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55974331/unity-export-android-64-bit), but it is not identical.

1. In my Android Build settings I have ticked "Build App Bundle.
2. Scripting back-end = IL2CPP
3. API Compatibility Level = .NET Standard 2.0
4. Target architectures = ARMv7, ARM64, x86

When I build the AAB file and upload it to Google, I am given the error

> The following APKs or App Bundles are available to 64-bit devices, but they only have 32-bit native code: 6.

When I build the game I can see the progress window saying it is building the 64 bit source. So why does Google keep telling me it doesn't contain a 64 bit version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [unity forum](https://forum.unity.com/threads/successful-unity-aab-build-not-compliant-with-the-google-play-64-bit-requirement.729035/):

> x86 is used by less than 0.4% of all Android devices, so it shouldn't
>   have any real impact.
>
> You may probably already noticed but in 2019.2 x86 target is marked as
>   deprecated, in 2019.3 it will be removed completely.

Deselect **x86** architecture in Player Settings.

Comment: That worked, thanks. I was unaware that x86 was such a small percentage, which is why I was originally reluctant to disable it.

Thank you!